# How to filter records by timestap

Tags: algolia, instantsearch.js

I have a list of events with start time and i need to display only future events. Basically something like `startTime > now`.

Any suggestions?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a record with a date as an integer, you can use a filter on numerical values.

For example, if you have a record like that:

```
{
  "objectID": 1,
  "eventName": "Algolia Search party",
  "startTime": 1507705690 //Wednesday, October 11, 2017 7:08:10 AM in timestamp
}
```

You can search on top with something like:

```
index.search({
  filters: 'startTime > ' + new Date().getTime()
});
```

You can find more here: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/searching/filtering/?language=php#filter-by-numerical-value

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Needed a small modification for my case:`Math.round(+new Date()/1000)` for unix timestamp